# I can't search through pdf file

Tags: pdf, full-text-search, ocr, encode

I have a problem with searching in a pdf file.

I found out the problem is caused by wrong encode type. I have read on a forum there is nothing i can do about it only if I contact the pdf file's creator to use correct encode type,but for me it is not possible.

[image]

[You can see on this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKXQv.jpg) i am looking for a certain word that I know it is contained in the document for sure, but it can't find it.

[image]

[The rectangular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwmKv.jpg) characters are hungarian accent letters in the pdf document.

What I did is export the whole pdf to image files jpeg2000 or jpg or tif,recombine all the pages to a single pdf file and run OCR but with this approach the file became too large, with lower resolution it lost to much detail so it was not usable.(but it became searchable)

Does anyone know a way to produce a good quality searchable pdf file?

Comment: But you say you cannot ask its author for a better PDF, so why your last question? If you post a link to that file we could at least verify that your forum advisors are correct.

Comment: That forum topic was not related with my problem.
I could ask maybe, but i would like to find out if is there any general way for solving this kind of problem.
I fount pdf files in the past that were corrupt and had the same problem.
As i mentioned 
exporting the pdf and re combine the exported files then run an OCR is a solution but it comes with bigger file size and actually lowered resolution.

I am wondering maybe it it possible to get data straight from the pdf file type,or maybe there is a simplier solution.

Comment: There are many, many different ways to create a perfectly correct and viewable PDF. Its text may or may not be extractable. That is why I'd like to see the file. If you cannot, for example, simply *select* the text, then it may not *be* "text". If you can, and you can copy it with a good PDF viewer, then it may be possible to mechanically extract. But we don't know what will work without seeing the file.

Comment: Here is the not well behaving pdf file, it is computing science in hungarian.
http://www.cs.bme.hu/~fleiner/jegyzet/NESZ.pdf

Comment: The encoding is actually correct, but the accent U+0301 is in the wrong position! `Gr{U+0301}afok` – it should be *behind* the `a`. This is most likely Acrobat's problem. No idea how to fix. It may be off-topic for Stack Overflow after all.